# Caching without Vary By option?

Tags: caching

When selecting a component's Cacheability, the Vary By options control the cache key.  What happens if I cache a rendering but do not specify a Vary By option?  Also- does Sitecore generate a different cache key depending on if the rendering has a datasource or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't select Vary By Options, Then Sitecore will generate a cache key for the rendering that is unique per the **context language**, Which means the Html output in the cache will be the same for the same rendering on all pages within **same language**

If you select "**Vary by Data**" option and didn't set the datasource for rendering, Sitecore will use the **Context Page Item ID** (Plus context language) to generate the cache key, Which means the Html output in the cache will be the same on the **same page on same language**.

If you select "**Vary by Data**" option and you set the datasource for rendering, Sitecore will use the **datasource item ID** (Plus context language) to generate the cache key, Which means the Html output in the cache will be the same if the rendering is using the same **datasource item** within same language context.